# unable to package app for android using sencha touch 2

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to package the demo example (Tabs) for andrdoi.I generated the certificate file using keytool and the alias name is (alias_name).  When i try to package using command :sencha package c:\xampp\htdocs\sench\ss.json.I am getting error "JSON format error , please verify syntax".  How can i fix this error.

My json file :

```
{
    "applicationName":"test app",
    "applicationId":"com.sench.test",
    "versionString":"1.0",
    "iconName":"icon.png",
    "inputPath":"C:\xampp\htdocs\sench\",
    "outputPath":"c:\output",
    "configuration":"Debug",
    "platform":"AndroidEmulator",
    "certificatePath":"C:\my-release-key.keystore",
    "certificateAlias":"alias_name",
    "sdkPath":"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk",
    "androidAPILevel":"7",
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "landscapeLeft",
        "landscapeRight",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used `\` in your JSON file and in JSON/JavaScript that means you want to [escape](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_escape_characters.cfm) something. To get around this, simply add `\` again so each time you use backslash, it knows you do not want to escape anything.

```
"sdkPath":"C:\\Program Files\\Android\\android-sdk"
```